# Hide Text on Window Title Headers (Gnome)

Tags: gnome, window, titlebar

I need to hide the text on the window title headers, which usually shows the application name. It is disruptive to me because I have many window applications running in parallel on the same screen and I know their names already.

This is particularly for an application called Blender, which I think is non-GTK.

I guess an easy way to do it is editing `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` and giving the text a color identical to the header's background, but I'm inexperienced in css and couldn't find the right code to do that.

**INTENDED CHANGE**

**Before**
[image: 1]

**After**
[image: 2]

Comment: Which gnome version? Things are changing currently. But blender doesn't seem to use GTK, so gtk.css won't be the right place. To narrow it down: Does the header change, if you use gnome-tweaks?

Comment: Yes it does, Blender's header changes when I change theme on Tweaks>Legacy Applications section. My current theme is Adw-dark. I'm guessing I must modify the theme itself at /usr/share/themes/Adw-dark/... one of those files. My gnome is 43.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tweak must be in the metacity-theme-?.xml file.(?=1 to 3 whatever is present)

Define a frame style (or alter one) like this:

```
<frame_style name="normal_unfocused" geometry="normal">
  <piece position="entire_background" draw_ops="background"/>
  <piece position="title" draw_ops="title_normal"/>
```

The "draw_ops" looks like this:

```
<draw_ops name="title_normal">   <include name="title_text"/> </draw_ops>
```

and (inherited):

```
<draw_ops name="title_text">
  <clip x="0" y="0" width="width" height="height"/>
  <title color="#747474"
         x="(width - title_width) / 2" y="(height - title_height) / 2"/>
</draw_ops>
```

So it depends on your theme, this is just a hint. In the last code example you could alter the title_color to your background color.

Comment: Which theme is the example taken from? Adwaita doesn't seem to include metacity files anymore. Fluent Dark theme comes with but no mention to title color in the xml. Any theme suggestion will be appreciated in this regard and great answer/hint so far!

Comment: Metacity is the fallback of ubuntu, since they expect GTK3 with CSD decorations. Since blender and others don't have them there should be some "fallback" theme with metacity. The example was taken from [my theme](https://www.pling.com/p/1424967/)  I'll check with ubuntu later on...